# Error when I add connection string in a UserControl

Tags: vb.net

I am facing a weird problem, I am trying to create Usercontrol (Add_companies)and add it to panel 
Everything work fine but when I add the connection to the user control I face this error :

The variable 'Add_companies1' is either undeclared or was never assigned.

And this is my connection:

```
Protected configuracion As ConnectionStringSettings = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("Conn")
Dim Conn As New SqlConnection(configuracion.ConnectionString)
Public Cmd As SqlCommand
```

[Error one image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rVLe2.png)

[where the error code must be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWRgw.png)

and when i go to the code line error there's nothing.

Comment: Can you please post a code including the line where you've used this variable `Add_companies1`. Your error is probably caused by referring `Add_companies1` which is not declared or assigned.

Comment: yes i dont know why it referring to "Add_companies1" and my Usercontrol name is "Add_companies"
this connection work perfects in all forms but when i use it the Usercontrol
the form2 where i using the panel give me error in the design.

Comment: Which statement is getting the error?

Comment: I'm sure this error can be triggered even comment these code.

Comment: I added pictures to the error, take look please

Comment: Try replacing `Me.Add_companies1` to `Me.Add_companies`

Comment: No the error back and now its in "Me.Add_companies"
this is weird !!

Comment: Don't post pictures of code, they don't help. Post the code that gets the error and tell us exactly which statement gets the error.

Comment: @Blackwood this is what upset me, there's no Error in the code

Comment: `Add_companies1` is the name of the usercontrol placed on the form;  just like Button1, Button2, etc.  Most likely there is something in the usercontrol code that will not compile.  Such errors are not uncommon when working with UserControls or Derived controls.  The safest thing to do when making changes to a UserControl that is currently placed on a form's design surface is to close the form designer first.  Make your changes and perform a rebuild of the project.  Then open your form designer again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Protected configuracion As ConnectionStringSettings = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("Conn")
Dim Conn As New SqlConnection(configuracion.ConnectionString)
Public Cmd As SqlCommand
```

You indicate that you placed this code in your UserControl and now the Form designer is throwing errors.  The VS IDE is loading and running an instance of the usercontrol when it is placed on the design surface.

These three lines of code would have to be placed at the class level to support the `Protected` and `Public` access modifiers.  The issue is that the designer is not able to retrieve `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("Conn")` so `configuracion` is null when it is used in `Dim Conn As New SqlConnection(configuracion.ConnectionString)`.

When you use the syntax: `Dim var as New Something()` at the class level, the compiler converts that to  `Dim var as Something` and places `var = New Something()` into the class constructor (Sub New) code.

To fix this problem you need to prevent code that will throw an error while in design mode from executing.  All controls have a Boolean property named `DesignMode` for this purpose.  Note that `DesignMode` will not be valid if used in the constructor code, so trying to use it there will fail.

```
Imports System.Configuration
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class Add_companies
    Protected configuracion As ConnectionStringSettings
    Private Conn As SqlConnection
    Public Cmd As SqlCommand

    Private Sub Add_companies_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        If Not Me.DesignMode Then
            configuracion = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("Conn")
            Conn = New SqlConnection(configuracion.ConnectionString)
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```